# Apache POIでtsvファイルを読み込む方法

Tags: java, csv, apache-poi

Javaを使ってtsvファイルをxlsx形式に変換する方法を探しています。
出来ればApachePOIを使って実現できないでしょうか？

Comment: 本家SOに類似の質問 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077264/convert-csv-to-xls-xlsx-using-apache-poi がありました。未検証で恐縮ですが、解決済みの回答にあるコードの11行目(while文の下の行)の","を"\t"に換えることで実現できませんか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tab区切りの場合は以下のコードで可能です。

poi 3.13 + poi-ooxml 3.13で動作検証しました。

```
public void csvToXLSX() throws Exception {
  String classpath = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
  String csvFileAddress = classpath + "/test_tab.csv"; // csv file address
  String xlsxFileAddress = classpath + "/test_tab.xlsx"; // xlsx file  address
  XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("sheet1");
  String currentLine = null;
  int RowNum = 0;
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileAddress));
  while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String str[] = currentLine.split("\\t");
    RowNum++;
    XSSFRow currentRow = sheet.createRow(RowNum);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(str[i]);
    }
  }

  FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(xlsxFileAddress);
  workBook.write(fileOutputStream);
  fileOutputStream.close();
  System.out.println("Done");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

海外のStackOverflowに回答がありましたので、
翻訳したものを記載します。

----------------------------------------------------------------

以下のメソッドを利用することで、Apache-POIを使用しながら.xlsxファイルを作成できます。

```
public static void csvToXLSX() {
    try {
        String csvFileAddress = "test.csv"; //csv file address
        String xlsxFileAddress = "test.xlsx"; //xlsx file address
        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("sheet1");
        String currentLine=null;
        int RowNum=0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileAddress));
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String str[] = currentLine.split(",");
            RowNum++;
            XSSFRow currentRow=sheet.createRow(RowNum);
            for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
                currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(str[i]);
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =  new FileOutputStream(xlsxFileAddress);
        workBook.write(fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage()+"Exception in try");
    }
}
```

回答者[sankumarsingh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624003/sankumarsingh)